# AS400 Db2400 SQL Query OR Conditions

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am doing a query on the data below

```
A       B           C           D   E
-----   --------    --------    --- ---
1       20140911    20140916    HPS  32
2       20140901    20140901    PLV   8
3       20140901    20140903    HPS  24
```

and when I run this query

```
select A, B, C, D, E 
from TABLE1 where (A = '1') and
(
    ( B >= 20140915 AND C <= 201401012 ) 
    OR 
    ( B < 20140915 AND C > 201401012 ) 
    OR 
    ( C > 201401012 AND B <= 201401012 AND B >= 20140915 ) 
    OR 
    ( C >= 20140915 AND C <= 201401012 AND B < 20140915 ) 
)
```

as output I get

```
A       B           C           D   E
-----   --------    --------    --- ---
1       20140911    20140916    HPS  32
```

and when with the query I add a condition (**AND D = 'HPS'**) like the one below

```
select A, B, C, D, E from TABLE1 where (A = '1' AND D = 'HPS')
and
(
    ( B >= 20140915 AND C <= 201401012 ) 
    OR 
    ( B < 20140915 AND C > 201401012 ) 
    OR 
    ( C > 201401012 AND B <= 201401012 AND B >= 20140915 ) 
    OR 
    ( C >= 20140915 AND C <= 201401012 AND B < 20140915 ) 
)
```

**It does not return any output. and I cannot understand why this is happening.**

Comment: What are the field definitions?

Comment: A - Char 5
B - Numeric 8,0
C - Numeric 8,0
D - Char 3
E - Decimal 5,2

the query is being submitted from the iSeries Navigator

Comment: It works with the example data in iNav 'Run SQL Scripts' exactly as coded for me.

Comment: I have tried it again and now is working I don't now what happened exactly, We have sent a question to IBM about it maybe there is a problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Side note: your last two date-range conditions (the ones with three comparisons) will always return false with those values.  It's possible you've been a victim of stale index stats or similar, which can be fixed via regular maintenance tasks, or just letting the system get caught up a little.  Oh, for positive continuous-range types (like date/time/timestamps), it's best to use [an exclusive upper bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (`<`) for comparisons.

Comment: the last 2 statement will return data if the dates are overlapping either the start date or the end date of the selection criteria you are giving. It is tried and tested the condition